# When tagging EC2 instances, is it possible to automatically tag the attached services (such as volumes)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible in AWS to automatically tag services that are related to an EC2 instance when tagging the EC2 instance itself? To illustrate, when I tag the EC2 instance in the tag manager, services related to the EC2 (such as volumes) remain untagged. Manually tagging all related resources seems like a lot of redundant work - is there any way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

Tag changes generate CloudWatch Events so you can create and call AWS Lambda to tag related resources.